# Driving on 3 cylinder

Tags: engine, idle

So I have a 4 cylinder engine however one of the piston is stuck And will not fire... That being said we have been driving this rough car for months no other problem other than the "skipped" piston making it a rough idle. Lately though it doeant seem to want to idle in gear. I have to put it in neutral or be revving the engine to keep rmps up.... Is thisfixable?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What have you done to try and fix the issue? Do you know what might be wrong with it in the first place which isn't allowing it to run on the fourth cylinder? There could be a plethora of peripheral things wrong with it now that you've been running it for so long on just the three cylinders. More information would be great in this case. Please start with what is the year/make/model/engine/mileage of the car in question.

Comment: What is the make, model, year and engine of the car? Why do you think one cylinder isn't firing?

Comment: What does "idle in gear" mean? I'm personally amazed that a 4 cylinder engine would develop enough torque when idling on 3 cylinders, to allow the driver to coast along at idle speed (which is how I interpret your question)